# KeyError: 'Value' when running slither on a contract

Tags: python-3.x, solidity

Python version: 3.8.5
Solc version: 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b.Linux.g++
Slither version: 0.6.13

When trying to run `slither .` on a solidity contract I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 692, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 79, in process_all
    ) = process_single(compilation, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 62, in process_single
    slither = Slither(target, ast_format=ast, **vars(args))
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._parser.analyze_contracts()
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slitherSolc.py", line 338, in analyze_contracts
    self._analyze_first_part(contracts_to_be_analyzed, libraries)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slitherSolc.py", line 395, in _analyze_first_part
    self._parse_struct_var_modifiers_functions(contract)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slitherSolc.py", line 461, in _parse_struct_var_modifiers_functions
    contract.parse_state_variables()
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/contract.py", line 303, in parse_state_variables
    var_parser = StateVariableSolc(var, varNotParsed)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/variables/state_variable.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__(variable, variable_data)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/variables/variable_declaration.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._init_from_declaration(variable_data, variable_data["value"])
KeyError: 'value'
ERROR:root:None
ERROR:root:Error in .
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 692, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 79, in process_all
    ) = process_single(compilation, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 62, in process_single
    slither = Slither(target, ast_format=ast, **vars(args))
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._parser.analyze_contracts()
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slitherSolc.py", line 338, in analyze_contracts
    self._analyze_first_part(contracts_to_be_analyzed, libraries)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slitherSolc.py", line 395, in _analyze_first_part
    self._parse_struct_var_modifiers_functions(contract)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slitherSolc.py", line 461, in _parse_struct_var_modifiers_functions
    contract.parse_state_variables()
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/declarations/contract.py", line 303, in parse_state_variables
    var_parser = StateVariableSolc(var, varNotParsed)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/variables/state_variable.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__(variable, variable_data)
  File "/home/wirel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/variables/variable_declaration.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._init_from_declaration(variable_data, variable_data["value"])
KeyError: 'value'
```

**Here is the contract:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
//     _____          __         .____           __    __                       
//    /  _  \  __ ___/  |_  ____ |    |    _____/  |__/  |_  ___________ ___.__.
//   /  /_\  \|  |  \   __\/  _ \|    |   /  _ \   __\   __\/ __ \_  __ <   |  |
//  /    |    \  |  /|  | (  <_> )    |__(  <_> )  |  |  | \  ___/|  | \/\___  |
//  \____|__  /____/ |__|  \____/|_______ \____/|__|  |__|  \___  >__|   / ____|
//         \/                           \/                     \/       \/     
// Automatically draws a winner once the payout threshold is met

pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract AutoLottery {
    address[] public players;
    uint256 public totalPayoutValue;
    uint256 public currentPrizePool;
    address public lastWinner;
    uint256 public lastPayout;
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        totalPayoutValue = 0 ether;
        currentPrizePool = 0 ether;
        lastPayout = 0 ether;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    // Allow a player to enter, value entered must be 0.01 or greater
    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= 0.01 ether, "You must enter 0.01 or more Ether!");
        players.push(msg.sender);
        currentPrizePool += msg.value;
        if (address(this).balance >= 1.00 ether) {
            winner();
        }
    }

    // Choose a winner at random
    function winner() internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= 1.00 ether, "Not enough eth in prize pool!");

        uint index = random() % players.length;
        
        totalPayoutValue += address(this).balance;
        lastWinner = players[index];
        lastPayout = address(this).balance;
        
        payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);
        
        delete players;
    }

    // Creates a random number
    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encode(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));
    }

    // Returns a list of all currently entered players
    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
    
    // The owner of the contract can force a draw if its been too long since the last draw
    function emergencyDraw() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this method!");
        
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        
        totalPayoutValue += address(this).balance;
        lastWinner = players[index];
        lastPayout = address(this).balance;
        
        payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);
        
        delete players;
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I could solve this issue? So far I have tried re-installing python, slither and solc and even tried installing slither from docker but get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error within Slither itself, it should be fixed in new update.

Comment: Hi, how can I use Slither to test sample contract distributed by the docker image. Nearly all of them have compiler versions 0.4.15. This makes it possible to use them for demonstrations and using solc-select, I can not have that version. What do you suggest?